# Neo4J Java API - Shortest Path for specific node label or excluding a particular relationship

Tags: java, neo4j, shortest-path

I'm building a simple app using Neo4J and I'm using the Java API.

I have two node labels in my graph
1. Class
2. Instance

I want to get the shortest path between two nodes, **(a:Instance)** and **(b:Instance)**

Assume that there are 2 paths connecting the nodes.

Path 1:

```
(a:Instance)-[:is_a]->(x:Class)<-[:is_a]-(b:Instance)
```

Path 2:

```
(a:Instance)-[:relType1]->(z:Instance)-[:relType2]->(y:Instance)<-[relType3]-(b:Instance)
```

What I want for the result is the **Path 2**. I want the path is only involving nodes with **Instance** label. Or if I can't do that, I want the path that doesn't contain an **is_a** relationship type.

My current code is something like this:

```
PathFinder<Path> finder = GraphAlgoFactory.shortestPath(PathExpanders.allTypesAndDirections(), CommonCons.MAX_HOP );
Node startNode;
Node endNode;

Path path = finder.findSinglePath(startNode, endNode);
```

In PathExpanders, I don't see there is exist a filter for specific node label. And also I don't see in PathExpander that can includes all relationship types **except** one particular relationship type.

Is there a way to achieve that??
I just don't want a node with a **Class** label or a relationship with **is_a** type exist in my path.

Sorry for my English

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it

I used **PathExpanderBuilder** to build my own PathExpander. Firstly, I set my PathExpander to cover all types and directions. After that, I removed the **is_a** RelationshipType from the expander.

My final code is look like this:

```
PathExpanderBuilder peBuilder = PathExpanderBuilder.allTypesAndDirections().remove(RelationshipType.withName(CommonCons.REL_IS_A));
PathFinder<Path> finder = GraphAlgoFactory.shortestPath(peBuilder.build(), CommonCons.MAX_HOP );
Node startNode;
Node endNode;

Path path = finder.findSinglePath(startNode, endNode);
```